# Loosing Elements as "None" by adding ".string" command in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to programming so I am hesitant to ask this question. Yet I couldn't find an answer browsing this page so far.

I use BeautifulSoup to extract the paragraphs of a German Newspaper. It works kind of fine but some paragraphs seem to dissapear / come out as "None" when I add the `.string` command to the variable containing the paragraphs including tags.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2020-05/konsumstimmung-handel-modebranche-einkaufen-corona"
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, features="html.parser")
para = soup.find_all('p', 'paragraph article__item')

for each in para:
    print(each.string)

link_1 = soup.find('a', 'article-pagination__link').get('href')


#next page

url_1 = link_1
r = requests.get(url_1)
r_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, features="html.parser")
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p', 'article__item'):
    print(paragraph.string)
```

The last line ist important: `print(paragraph.string)`

So basically: Without the `.string` everything works fine, I get every paragraph output. Using the `.string` command some paragraphs get swallowed and output as "None".

Whats up with that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.text` instead of `.string`. There is the subtle difference between them - this is what `.string` does:

> If this element has a single string child, return  value is that
>   string. If this element has one child tag,  return value is the
>   'string' attribute of the child tag,  recursively. If this element is
>   itself a string, has no  children, **or has more than one child, return
>   value is None**.

and this is what `.text` does:

> Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator.

Comment: On your page, if you look at the paragraphs where string returns None, you will see that they have an embedded link or span element, whereas text will return the concatenated paragraph text.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Next time I will look up the commands if I have trouble with one of them.
The difference between the paragraphs that got put out with ".string" versus the ones that did not was simply the <br>, which counts as a "child I suppose.